# Gnome does not recognize shortcuts with Level_3 key symbols

Tags: unity, gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have modified my keyboard layout in the following way using `xkb`:

1. CapsLock key has been reassigned to act as Control_L.

```
replace key <CAPS> { [ Control_L ] };
modifier_map Control { <CAPS> };
```

2. Left control (<LCTL>) has been reassigned to act as a level3 modifier (ISO_Level3_Shift).

```
replace key <LCTL> {
  type[Group1] = "ONE_LEVEL",
  symbols[Group1] = [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
};
include "level3(modifier_mapping)"
```

3. Level 3 of the number 2 key (<AE02>) has been assigned to the symbol F2.

```
key <AE02> {[2, at, F2]};
```

---

### The problem:

On pressing `LCtrl+2` on the keyboard, `xev` shows that the keysymbol `F2` is being registered. Also, `Alt+F2` has been assigned to open up the mini command prompt in gnome's keyboard shortcut settings. This shortcut works when I press the actual `F2` key on the keyboard. But it does *not* work with `Alt+LCtrl+2`, which it should.

I can tell that gnome shortcuts do recognize these xkb changes partially, since `CapsLock+Alt+t` opens up the terminal. Only shortcuts with level 3 modifiers seem to be a problem for now.

#### Another example:

I have assigned level3 symbol for the `;` to `PgDown` (or `Next`).

`Super+PgDown` should move to next desktop. This works when the actual PgDown key is pressed on the keyboard, but fails to work with `Super+LCtrl+;`. (`xev` does show that `LCtrl+;` is registered as PageDown)

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension#Caps_hjkl_as_vimlike_arrow_keys maybe trying to adapt this section of the arch wiki to your keymaps could work.

Answer (score 0):

### edits after testing

after thinking for a bit and some testing I realized that the first two steps are not required here. They are only necessary to remap a function of a key as in the example in the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension#Caps_hjkl_as_vimlike_arrow_keys). Here only using the `actions` for your remaps will suffice.

```
...
    key <AE02> { symbols[Group1]= [               2,               NoSymbol,                                               FK02  ],
                 actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),             NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<FK02>, clearmods=levelThree) ]
    };
...
    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
```

### original answer

Adapting this [arch wiki section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension#Caps_hjkl_as_vimlike_arrow_keys) but using `Right Alt` instead of caps lock seems to work.

i needed to modify 3 files:

- 1. include the following in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/complete` (or writing your modifications in a new file and use `include "custom_file"` might be a better idea. I did it in the same file for simplicity)

```
default xkb_types "complete" {
    include "basic"
    include "mousekeys"
    include "pc"
    include "iso9995"
    include "level5"
    include "extra"
    include "numpad"

    type "CUST_ALT" {
        modifiers = Shift+LevelThree;
        map[None] = Level1;
        map[Shift] = Level2;
        map[LevelThree] = Level3;
        map[Shift+LevelThree] = Level3;
        level_name[Level1] = "Base";
        level_name[Level2] = "Shift";
        level_name[Level3] = "Level3";
   };


};
```

- 2. include the following in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/complete`

```
default xkb_compatibility "complete" {
    include "basic"
    augment "iso9995"
    augment "mousekeys"
    augment "accessx(full)"
    augment "misc"
    augment "xfree86"
    augment "level5"
    augment "caps(caps_lock)"

   interpret ISO_Level3_Shift+Any {
        useModMapMods= level1;
        virtualModifier= LevelThree;
        action= SetMods(modifiers=LevelThree);
    };


};
```

- 3. finally include you remaps in your symbols file

```
...
...
    key <AE02> {
       type= "CUST_ALT",
       symbols[Group1]= [               2,               NoSymbol,               FK02  ],
       actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<FK02>, clearmods=levelThree) ]
    };
...
...
    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
...
```

- note: the `NoSymbol` means "do not overwrite this keymap", differently to VoidSymbol which overwrites the keymap with "VoidSymbol"
- note2: make sure `include "level3(ralt_switch)"` is also inlcuded in your symbos file to map RightAlt as a third level modifier!

Answer (score 0):

(Edited, Corrected, Simplified)

**Explanation:**
When a key is emulated in xkb using the
`ISO_Level3_Shift` modifier, it will set a real modifier bit
(`Mod5`, as set up in the default xkb config files).
For Gnome keyboard shortcuts to recognize such an emulated key,
the extra modifier bit needs to be manually cleared as shown in
`@avila`'s answer, using `clearMods` of the `RedirectKey` action.

**Solution:**
As in `@avila`'s edited answer, modify `key <AE02>`
section as follows (the rest of OP's config stays the same):

```
key <AE02> {
    type    =   "THREE_LEVEL",
    symbols =   [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol ],
    actions =   [ NoAction(), NoAction(),
                    RedirectKey(
                        keycode = <FK02>,
                        clearmods = LevelThree
                    )
                ]
};
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, thanks for controlling, please take the [tour].